# How to v-model a input of type date

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input like so:

```
<input class="input" type="date" v-model="dob" />
```

`dob` is initialized as null, and works properly. For example 03/05/2006 models to `2006-03-05T00:00:00.000+00:0`.
However when `dob` is inititialized as `2006-03-05T00:00:00.000+00:0`, it doesn't show in the date input. How would I fix this.

Comment: To be clear, your `dob` variable is initialized as a date, and not a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: you could use to set a default value and have it changing afterwards.

```js
data() {
  return {
    initialDate: Date.now(),
  };
},
computed: {
  dob: {
    get() {
      return this.initialDate;
    },
    set(newValue) {
      this.initialDate = newValue;
    },
  },
},
```

---

Where is your input coming from ? It probably needs a UNIX timestamp like `1612454883231`. Try initializing it with `Date.now()` or maybe try `new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)`.
Also, `new Date('2006-03-05T00:00:00')` if you want to set it manually (and since it's a date of birth...).

If it doesn't work, you need to dig the documentation to see which format it accepts.

Comment: I already know that the accepted format is `yyyy-mm-dd`, I could use a computed property to get this, but then how I set the value of the input to the `dob` variable.

Comment: @bob341 use `@input="update"` listener to set updated value.

Comment: @bob341 If you're using vuex, a prop or any API call, you could also make the change on some hook (like `created`) and then, access/modify it. It doesn't need to be a `data` specifically.